# Why is it true that Max(X) = Min(-X) for a group X composed of numbers in Z

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

I'm looking for a formal explanation that won't involve calculus (if possible) that would explain why for every group of numbers X (such that all numbers in X are integers), Max(X) = Min(-X) (where -X denotes changing all values in group X to - the values).

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with $\max(x)$? After all, $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is just a single value, so the maximum value of $x$ is just $x$. That's not very exciting. Do you have **sets** in mind, perhaps?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain myself correctly. I've just edited the question

Comment: @vondip What if $X=\mathbb N$?

Comment: I think there is a minus sign missing. Also, what you call a group is usually known as a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are implicitly asking about is the property of the **Least Upper Bound** and the **Greatest Lower Bound**, and the relationship between the two. Though I won't bother you with the details in this answer, you should read up on them if you are interested.

Now to the formal answer of your question, as requested:

**Proposition:** For any $X \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, $\max{(X)} = \min{(-X)}$, where $-X = \{x \in X \mid x \cdot (-1) \}$

**Proof:**

Take $x \in X$ s.t. $x = \max(X)$. Now take $-x \in -X$. Suppose $-x$ is not the minimal element of $-X$. Then there exists $-y \in Y$ s.t. $-x > -y$ and $-y = \min(-X)$. Now consider the elements of $X$ that correspond to $-y$ and $-x$: because we have $-y \in -X$, there must exist a $(-y \cdot (-1)) \in X$. Similar for $-x$, as we know.

But if $-x > -y$, then $x < y$. But we know $x$ is the largest element of $X$, and $y>x$ implies that $y = \max(X)$, which is a contradiction. So our supposition that $-x$ is not the minimal element of $-X$ must be false. So by contradiction, $-x = \min(-X)$.

Comment: This answer assumes $\max (X)$ always exists.

Comment: yes, assuming that the set $X$ is always nonempty and finite.